# Configurations and combinations in a chess board

Tags: combinations

In a chessboard, a pawn needs to move from the lower left to the upper right corner.

a) Find the number of possible paths if one "move" is a combination consisting of 3-steps up and 4-steps right, for example, R-UU-RR-UU-RR-UUU-RR is one possible path

b) Find the number of possible configurations if all pieces are now placed in lines 1&2, and if the only limitation is that the queen can be to a same-color block and that paws can only occupy line 1

For a, I do something like

a) Each path is 14 moves in total but we need to move in total by 7 blocks right(R) in 3 moves and by 7 blocks up(U) in 4 moves. So we have $C(7,3)\cdot C(7,4)$ possible paths.

b) I would say that we have for pawns 8! ways, and then 2! for each of the towers, rooks, and horses, 1 way for the king, and 1 way for the queen. However, I am troubled by the condition given for the queen, which I guess indicates that I should consider all configurations in the 1rst line, not necessarily the "correct one". In such a case what the solution would be?

Comment: why downvoting? The problem is clear, and I have put my tried answer. Please comment if you can be useful, otherwise don't downvote without providing any hint/help

Comment: "Find the number of possible paths if one "move" is a combination consists of 3-steps up and 4-steps right, for example, R-UU-RR-UU-RR-UUU-RR is one possible path": I don't understand how the example given represents 3 steps up and 4 steps to the right.

Comment: @user2661923 Well, there are four $R$-blocks (pawn moves right , possibly more than one step) and three $U$-blocks (pawn moves up,possibly more than one step).

Comment: @user2661923, yes, as Peter said, one move is more than one block, so R-UU-RR-UU-RR-UUU-RR is : 1rst move 1R, 2nd move is 2blocks U, 3rd move is 2 blocks Right etc, in total covering 14 blocks in 7 moves/steps.

Comment: The phrasing of (a) is still unnecessarily confusing. Even in your own solution you use "move" for a movement in one direction only (right or up, but not both) whereas the question says "move" for a combined sequence of right *and* up movements. You could say the pawn must move one square at a time, either right or up, must start with a rightward move and must change direction exactly six times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part A is a Stars and Bars problem.

For Stars and Bars theory, see
[this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) and
[this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Consider the number of solutions to the following:

- $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 7.$
- $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}$.

You make the change of variable $y_i = x_i - 1.$

Then, you are computing the number of solutions to

- $y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 = (7-4).$
- $y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

By Stars and Bars theory, the number of solutions is

$$\binom{[7-4] + [4-1]}{4-1} = \binom{6}{3}.$$

This takes care of the $4$ *right* moves.

For the $3$ *up* moves, you want the number of solutions to

- $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 7.$
- $x_1, x_2, x_3, \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}$.

You make the change of variable $y_i = x_i - 1.$

Then, you are computing the number of solutions to

- $y_1 + y_2 + y_3 = (7-3).$
- $y_1, y_2, y_3, \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

By Stars and Bars theory, the number of solutions is

$$\binom{[7-3] + [3-1]}{3-1} = \binom{6}{2}.$$

So, the total number of variations is the cross product represented by

$$\binom{6}{3} \times \binom{6}{2}.$$

---

For Part B, I interpret it to mean that you are supposed to regard the pawns as distinguishable.  This suggests that (for example) the two rooks are also distinguishable from each other.  So, the only constraints are that

- All the pawns go on the 1st rank, and the pieces go on the 2nd rank.
- The queen is supposed to get her color, which means that the white queen must be placed on a white square.

Under this very simplistic (and quite possible erroneous) interpretation, the computation is simply

$$\frac{1}{2} \times 8! \times 8!. \tag1 $$

In (1) above, the first factor represents that, by symmetry, exactly half of the configurations will result in the Queen on a white square.

In (1) above, the 3rd factor represents that the rooks, knights, bishops, king and queen are all distinguishable, so you are computing the number of ways of positioning $8$ distinguishable pieces.

---

Part B continued:

It is very doubtful that the my first interpretation above is the one intended by the problem composer.  Presumably, the reason that chess pieces are involved is that you are supposed to assume that (for example) the two rooks are indistinguishable from each other.

However, you can't have it both ways.  Given the problem as it is currently written, if (for example) the rooks are indistinguishable from each other, then so are the pawns.

This implies that there is only one way of positioning the 8 pawns, all in one row.

Consequently, under this new interpretation, the computation is

$$\frac{1}{2} \times \binom{8}{2} \times \binom{6}{2} \times \binom{4}{2} \times (2!). \tag2 $$

In (2) above, the first factor (again) uses a symmetry argument to consider that the queen must be on a white square.  Then, the next three factors represent the number of ways of positioning, in order, the rooks, knights, and bishops.  Then, the last factor represents the number of ways of positioning the king and queen.